# multiple non-static default parameters c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to find an elegant way to declare an initiating function that uses default values currently stored in my object (non-static values). I would basically like to do something like this.

```
class A{
    A([...], 
      string defaultName, 
      vector<string> defaultUrls, 
      map<string, string> defaultParams);

    [...]

    void initSomething(string defaultName = mDefaultName,
                  vector<string> defaultUrls = mDefaultUrls ,
                  map<string, string> defaultParams =mDefaultParams);

    private:
    string mDefaultName;
    vector<string> mDefaultUrls;
    map<string, string> mDefaultParams;
    [...]
}
```

I know I could overload the `initSomething()` function, but I would get something like this:

```
void initSomething(){
    initSomething(mDefaultName, mDefaultUrls, mDefaultParams);
}

void initSomething(string defaultName){
    initSomething(defaultName, mDefaultUrls, mDefaultParams);
}

void initSomething(vector<string> defaultUrls = mDefaultUrls){
    initSomething(mDefaultName, mDefaultUrls, mDefaultParams);
}

void initSomething(map<string, string> defaultParams){
    initSomething(mDefaultName, mDefaultUrls, defaultParams);
}

void initSomething(string defaultName, vector<string> defaultUrls){
    initSomething(mDefaultName, mDefaultUrls, mDefaultParams);
}

void initSomething(string defaultName,  map<string, string> defaultParams){
    initSomething(defaultName, mDefaultUrls, defaultParams);
}

void initSomething(vector<string> defaultUrls, map<string, string> defaultParams){
    initSomething(mDefaultName, defaultUrls, defaultParams);
}

void initSomething(string defaultName,
              vector<string> defaultUrls,
              map<string, string> defaultParams);
```

It's pretty ugly and so huge it makes the whole header file harder to read and grasp the meaning of it.

I also thought about something else:

```
void initSomething(string defaultName = "",
              vector<string> defaultUrls = vector<string>(),
              map<string, string> defaultParams = map<string, string>()){
    if (defaultName == "") {
        defaultName = mDefaultName;
    }

    if (defaultUrls.empty()) {
        defaultUrls = mDefaultUrls;
    }

    if (defaultParams.empty()) {
        defaultParams = mDefaultParams;
    }

    [...] 
}
```

It's still ugly and has the drawback of not letting one of these values truly be "empty" if the members variable are not set to empty before calling the initSomething function. It also force someone checking the class to check the implementation of the method to understand that member default values will be used instead of empty ones.

I'm sure there's a way, a pattern or something to make this right but I haven't found it :(

Thanks for you help!

Comment: is this a strictly pre-c++11 question?

Comment: Oh, I haven't worked with c++11 yet, and since making changes to a pre-c++11 I'd say it would be nice to find a way to do it wihtout using c++11 features. I will read on that feature how ever, thx !

Comment: There are ways of doing this as you guessed, I would perhaps lean to the most basic version where you have a simple header entry of `void initSomething(string defaultName = NULL, vector<string> defaultUrls = NULL, map<string, string> defaultParams =NULL)` and have some logic in the cpp file to handle which parameters are present.  Not elegant but simple and effective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best that comes to my mind. Hope it helps.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct A{
    struct Default {};
    template <typename T>
    struct Parm{
        Parm() : gotHam(false), ham() {};
        Parm(const Default&) : gotHam(false), ham() {}
        Parm(const T& ham_) : gotHam(true), ham(ham_) {}
        operator bool(){
            return gotHam;
        }
        const bool gotHam;
        T ham;
    };
    A(std::string s_) : s(s_), i(5) {}

    void myFunction(Parm<std::string> s_ = Parm<std::string>(), Parm<int> i_ = Parm<int>()){
        std::string sValue = s_?s_.ham:s;
        int iValue = i_?i_.ham:i;
        std::cout << sValue << '\t' << iValue << std::endl;
    }

    std::string s;
    int i;
};

int main() {
   A a("defaulted");

   a.myFunction(std::string("caller provided")); //caller provided  5
   a.myFunction(A::Default()); //defaulted  5
   a.myFunction(); //defaulted  5

   a.myFunction(std::string("caller provided"), 10); //caller provided  10
   a.myFunction(A::Default(), 10); //defaulted  10
}
```

Notice that I deliberately made some design decisions, this code is not intended to be used as it is. For one thing, it doesn't handle reference parameters.

You can play with the code [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/931ddaa4f4d8d5f2).

Answer (score 0):

not an answer, but the only way I could paste code sensibly.
Below is an example of how to do the code part so that the one init will handle what you want however the parameters would have to be in the order you state for the definition of the function, however you can add simple overloads using the one base function and maintain the functionality with some simplicity and minimum fuss:

NB: the code below will not work with the overloads as I have used an integer return and parameters in the if statements, so there would not be any difference to the outcome, but it serves to illustrate the principle.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;
// this one can be private, or leave it public for versatility
int initSomething(string defaultName = "", vector<string> defaultUrls = vector<string>() , map<string, string> defaultParams = map<string, string>())
{
    int mDefaultName, mDefaultUrls, mDefaultParams = 0;
    if (defaultName == "")
        {
            //  set your default value here
            mDefaultName = 1;
        }
    if (defaultUrls == vector<string>())
        {
            //  and here
            mDefaultUrls = 2;
        }
    if (defaultParams == map<string, string>())
        {
            //  and finally here
            mDefaultParams = 3;
        }

    //  and here you can do whatever you want to do,
    //  and regardless of what form you call the one init will handle all the eventualities
    return mDefaultName + mDefaultUrls +mDefaultParams;
}
// variants
// these can be public
int initSomething()                                                     {initSomething("", vector<string>() ,map<string, string>());}
int initSomething(map<string, string>mystringmap)                       {initSomething("", vector<string>() ,mystringmap);}
int initSomething(vector<string> myvector)                              {initSomething("", myvector ,map<string, string>());}
int initSomething(vector<string> myvector, string>mystringmap)          {initSomething("", myvector ,mystringmap);}
int initSomething(string mystring)                                      {initSomething(mystring, vector<string>() ,map<string, string>());}
int initSomething(string mystring, vector<string> myvector)             {initSomething(mystring, myvector ,map<string, string>());}
int initSomething(string mystring, map<string, string>mystringmap)      {initSomething(mystring, vector<string>() ,mystringmap);}
// and so on
int main()
{
    cout << initSomething() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```